# Add additional link to responsive navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, navigation

I created a little responsive Navigation which works fine. I also want to add a link on the right side of my navigation for "Account".

My idea was to insert a div into a ul but I think that is not w3c conform.

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <div class="account">Account</div> 
</ul>
<a href="#" class="pull">Navigation</a>
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bb26gau3/)

Important is that i want the "account" on the right side, not side by side with the other navigation items. Under 700px screen size it should be under the contact li.

Should look like this: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3718/xneivu5d_png.htm

Sorry for my bad english. I hope you can understand my problem and maybe you have a good idea to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.navigation li{ float: left;}` CSS is pulling all `<li>` elements to the left.

Add the `<li>` tag for "Account" like so, with a new `account` class.

```
<li class="account"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
```

And add to your CSS:

```
.account{
    float: right !important;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bb26gau3/1/)

Also, you're going to have to adjust your media query width for menu collapse since the account is now appearing on a second line in a small screen width just before the menu collapses.

Comment: so easy and i tried to find a solution since hours..thank you so much! Is the other code ok or do you have any idea to optimize the code?

Comment: @user3700309 : if Dan helped you, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As what I thought you wanted was incorrect, I've decided to update my answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexCharlton/bb26gau3/3/

```
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Winterhalder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <div class="account">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="pull">Navigation</a>
</div>    
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.account {
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: You added a second line to the navbar (look at your fiddle vs. what OP posted as desired solution).  Also this is responsive and fixed pixel widths are not going to work.  It is not pulled to the right when on a wider screen.

Comment: ? Not on my screen, not sure what you're talking about it's all one line in the image.  I am not trying to get into an argument here.  You asked me to explain -1 and that's the reason.  In the picture he provided the actual navbar is the navbar for directupload.net, here's the actual image: http://s1.directupload.net/images/140818/xneivu5d.png

Comment: Do you see the actual image? Look at my link in previous comment

Comment: But what you thought he wanted was wrong.  Not a big deal...you misunderstood the question.  It's a -1 because it's just wrong.  Sorry, but you should edit it or delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Is it conform to use a div inside a ul?

Answer (score 0):

get your .account div OUT of the UL, and then you can style it. Like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Winterhalder</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Me</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="account">Account</div>  <a href="#" class="pull">Navigation</a>

</div>
```

then in CSS add this:

```
`/* NAVIGATION */
.navigation {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #34495E;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
.navigation ul {
width: auto;
max-width:960px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
float:left;
}
.account {
float:right;
margin:0px 20px
}
.navigation li {
display: inline;
float: left;
}
.navigation a, .account, .account a {
font: 400 14px Open Sans;
color: #FFF;
width: 140px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
}
.navigation a:hover, .navigation a:active {
color: #1abc9c;
}
.navigation a.pull {
display: none;
}
/* RESPONSIVE */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
.navigation {
    height: auto;
}
.navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
.navigation {
    height: auto;
}
.navigation ul {
    display: none;
}
.navigation li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation a.pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation a.pull:after {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
}
}`
```

You may need some minor adjustments because I'm not 100% sure if this is what you need, but it will help you to find out how to do it. See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgs6erk8/)

Comment: Margin is a bad idea in the `account` class. This is responsive and you shouldn't have that hard-coded.

Comment: Margin is a perfectly valid idea, otherwise, unless he adds a containing div, the .account div will end on the top right and in some browsers even slightly cut. It doesn't matter it's responsive, I code responsive solutions 365 days a year, is like saying Bootstrap and Foundation should kill their margins because they're using responsive grids

Comment: Margin is valid, but using a hard-coded pixel margin is not good.  Better to use `%`.  I am trying to be helpful, not critical.

Comment: well, that's why I added, literally **You may need some minor adjustments ** (specially on small screens). But I'm not taking this as critical, but as a valid  argument, which I consider wrong. When you say "hard coded" I assume you mean "fixed". If so, then you're against almost any existing responsive system, because they use fixed sizes on column aligned elements (as in this case). And here's the explanation why: when you use a percentage, you'll have this: let's say I use 1% percentage. In a 2400px width screen, I'll have 24px margin. In a 780px, I'll have 8px. (follows)

Comment: Instead, the common method is to use something like 5 or 10px FIXED margin, same applies for absolute positions, you need that space to be coherent across sizes and devices, not having elements "dancing" across the screen

Comment: I disagree.  If you look at my answer in the fiddle vs. yours you will see that one is better than the other.  Play around with the screen width and see what happens.  Separately, by moving the `account` outside of the `<li>` you remove the styling so it doesn't match in styling with the rest of the menu.

Comment: OK, you're right, I don't know what do you want me to tell you if even million sites and every responsive system disagree with you. Bottom line is you're against every existing responsive system, so if your system is better, then more power to you, you'd try to have everybody adopt your standards, but in the meanwhile, I'll keep with the accepted standards. Sorry if you perceive them as "wrong", but it's just you